# Delete btn in MVC.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I might need an extra set of eyes but my delete btn is not working it does return a message but after clicking yes or ok it doesn't remove the data i wanted to delete basically nothing happens, I think I have an issue with the inventory.Id part. thank you, and i know this is not a good question for other users but i appreciate the help.

```
       <tbody>
                      @foreach (var inventory in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(inventory.PartNumber, "Edit", "Inventory", new 
        { id = inventory.Id }, null)</td>
            <td>@inventory.PinNumber</td>
            <td>@inventory.PartQuantity </td>
            <td>@inventory.PartPrice </td>
            <td>@inventory.PartDescrption</td>
            <td> <button data-inventory-id="@inventory.Id" class="btn-link js-delete">Delete</button> </td>


        </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#inventories").DataTable();
            $("#inventories .js-delete").on("click", function () {
                var button = $(this);
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Part Number?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/inventory/" + button.attr("data-inventory-id"),
                        method: "DELETE",
                        success: function () {
                            button.parents("tr").remove();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

this is my Controller for the Delete Action:

```
 [HttpDelete]
        public void  DeleteInventory(int id)
        {
            var inventoryInDb = _context.Inventory.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);



            _context.Inventory.Remove(inventoryInDb);
            _context.SaveChanges();


        }
```

I don't have an API in the Tutorial i am following He has an API but I didn't create one. I am trying to get around that.
Thank you.

Comment: I'd try to diagnose where is the error happening. First check with browser's console and see if the data is actually being send to server. If not, add your id to console.log before your ajax call and see if it is actually getting the id you want.

Comment: The default type for a `<button>` element is `submit` - if this view is within a form, it's likely the page is being submitted, rather than allowing your jQuery code to handle the button. Should probably add `type="button"` to the button, but more importantly, follow @arunes's suggestion and check the developer console in your browser (normally enabled by pressing the F12 key on your keyboard).

Comment: I get 404 error in jquery --> xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null ); Filed to load resource. I think it is because i dont have an API im trying to use this way without using an API because this way is the shortest i found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In controller:
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
                {
                    if (id == null)
                    {
                        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                    }
                    Inventory inventory = _context.Inventory.Find(id);
                    if (inventory == null)
                    {
                        return HttpNotFound();
                    }
                    return View(inventory);
                }


in index add delete btn, this is an ajax call to the delete btn its used with dataTables to render data faster..

    {
"render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
               return '<a class="btn btn-danger" 
                href ="@Url.Action("Delete", "Inventory")/' + row.Id + '">Delete</a>'; 
 }
```

create a Delete view:

```
 @model InventoryTracker.Models.Inventory //this has to be re-named to your naming 
      convention.
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;

            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

        </div>
        }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using POST instead of DELETE as your ajax method?  Or simply using the $.post method.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you did not create a DELETE method in your back-end API. To find out for sure, open Chrome's developer tools (making sure you're on the console tab) and then click your button. You will see an error message that says "Method DELETE is not found" or something similar.

If it says "method is not allowed" then that has to do with permissions (the user clicking the button does not have permission to access that API).

Comment: I don't have an API but I added a Delete Action